# Remove text decoration from links

Tags: text-decorations, css

Why won't this remove the underline from the facebook and assassin industries links on [this page](http://www.hillsgarage.net).

```
.module_wpproad {
text-decoration:none;
border:none;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `text-decoration` attribute of links takes precedence over the `text-decoration` attribute of the container. You will need to be specific in your override:

```
.module_wpproad a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Thant makes sense. I though I did that. My syntax may have been incorrect or something. Thanks!!

Comment: In case it was too small to notice, the difference was `.module_wpproad a` instead of `.module_wpproad` :)